# Bluetooth not detecting any devices on Thinkpad T420s

Tags: bluetooth

I have elementary Freya installed. It seems Bluetooth is working. At least it's not hard- or software blocked and the lamp on my T420s is on as if Bluetooth was doing something. But when I try to find devices via blueman or the Bluetooth device manager in Freya it just searches and doesn't find anything.

Some output from the terminal:

```
joachim@Rumpelkiste:~$ uname -a
Linux Rumpelkiste 3.19.0-42-generic #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 18 10:24:49 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

joachim@Rumpelkiste:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21ce]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

joachim@Rumpelkiste:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 046d:c01e Logitech, Inc. MX518 Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b221 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd integrated camera
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

joachim@Rumpelkiste:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    1.855737] usb 3-1.4: Product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
[   15.364268] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[   16.346134] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   16.346157] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.346162] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.346164] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.346170] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.165088] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.165095] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.165100] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   19.200276] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   19.200279] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   19.200282] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  153.209785] usb 3-1.4: Product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
[ 1348.740479] usb 3-1.4: Product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
[ 1351.572954] usb 3-1.4: Product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
[ 1354.200843] usb 3-1.4: Product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
[ 1358.737264] usb 3-1.4: Product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device

joachim@Rumpelkiste:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.141526] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.153481] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    8.666901] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[   16.071900] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm

joachim@Rumpelkiste:~$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try resizing the "Device Search" window.

I was struggling in this same situation for long and for me the answer was simpler than I expected.